# Merging arrays in a particular format

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

```
var parent = [
  “aaaa”,
  “bbbb|{ba,bb,bc}”,
  ”cccc|{ca,cb,cc|{cca,ccb }}”,
  “dddd”
];  
var child = [
  “eeee”,
  “cccc|{cc|{ccc,ccd},cd}”,
  ”bbbb|{bd}”
];
```

I need to merge the elements of these two arrays in such a way that my resulting array is

```
var result = [
  “aaaa”,
  ”bbbb|{ba,bb,bc,bd}”,
  “cccc|{ca,cb,cc|{cca,ccb,ccc,ccd},cd”,
  ”dddd”,
  ”eeee”
];
```

**The order in which the elements appear in the RESULT  array is insignificant**. Only requirement is that the grouping of the elements should happen as given in the example.
Ie if an element has a ‘|’ operator prefixed by the same string is present in BASE  as well as CHILD array, they need to be merged as a single element in the resultant array as shown in the example. The ‘|’ can have a maximum of 2 occurrences in an array element. 
Can anyone suggest a logic to achieve the same through javascript?

Comment: If the grouping is relevant, then strings are the wrong data structure to represent this.

Comment: @Bergi—so perhaps the OP should split the strings into a suitable structure, merge them, then stringify again: `myLib.toObject(s0).merge(myLib.toObject(s1)).toArray()`.